# Can't get the element id on an onChange event in JavaScript via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this small HTML page which exposes my problem. I want to get the id of the first ancestor of my input element (`#input-1`). When the user changes the option value, the JavaScript code should get the id of the `#li-1` element and display it. Unfortunately all I get is a `undefined` and I don't know why.

The `parents()` function should traverse up the DOM tree and find the `li`  element, then get the id via the `.attr()` function

```js
$("#input-1").on("change", function(elem) {
  var id = $(elem).parents("li").attr("id");
  alert(id);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <li id="li-1">
    <div class="item-content item-input">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Test</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <select id="input-1">
            <option value="0">test0</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.closest()`

```
$("#input-1").on("change", function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
    alert(id);
})
```

Also, there is no need to use `elem` in this case, just use `this` in `$(this)`

**Demo**

```js
$("#input-1").on("change", function(elem) {
  console.log($(elem.target).closest("li").attr("id"))
  var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
  alert(id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li-1">
  <div class="item-content item-input">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-title item-label">Test</div>
      <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <select id="input-1">
          <option value="0">test0</option>
          <option value="1">test1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: if I use closest using the "elem" variable it doesn't work. With "this" it works

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini In your case, `elem` is the event. so you can use `elem.target` to get the element you do something with, like this: `$(elem.target).closest("li").attr("id")`

Answer (score 2):

I really advise to stop using jQuery for such simple operations, **and learn how the DOM works**. Here's the simple vanilla Javascript solution, which I consider so much cleaner.

What is being implicitly passed to an event listener is the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object that triggers it.

If you need to access the element the event occurred on, either use an ES5 function (like in my code example) and access the element inside the handler function using `this`, or use an ES6 arrow function ( `(event) => { /* ... */ }`) and then access the element using [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) inside the handler function.

Please note that the HTML you've shown is actually *invalid*, because `li` cannot exist without a parent `ul` or `ol`.

```js
document.getElementById('input-1').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  console.log(this.closest('li').id);
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="li-1">
    <div class="item-content item-input">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Test</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <select id="input-1">
            <option value="0">test0</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With modern JavaScript, you can even destructure the implicitly passed event object, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('input-1').addEventListener('change', ({target: elem})=>{
  console.log(elem.closest('li').id);
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="li-1">
    <div class="item-content item-input">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Test</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <select id="input-1">
            <option value="0">test0</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
 ({target: elem}) => { /* ... */ }
```

What this does: It says *from the object passed to this function, get me the `target` property and make it available as `elem` inside the function*.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `this` keyword

```
 $(this).parents('li').attr('id')
```

```js
$("#input-1").on("change", function(elem) {
  var id = $(this).parents('li').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <li id="li-1">
    <div class="item-content item-input">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Test</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <select id="input-1">
            <option value="0">test0</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok thank you. So why with "elem" it doesn't work? I thought "elem" would be the element which emits the change event

Comment: `elem` will return you the entire element. only `this` will return the target element. If you print both you will see the difference what I'm saying..

Comment: @Dood `elem` returns the event. if he wants the element, he can use `elem.target`

Answer (score 1):

Use .closest() or parent()
  You should get the parent of #input-1 not the select element

```
$("#input-1").on("change", function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    })
```

or

```
 $("#input-1").on("change", function(){
            var id = $(this).parents('li').attr('id');
            alert(id);
        })
```

Answer (score -3):

`<select id="input-1" onchange="GetId();">
            <option value="0">test0</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
    </select>`

declare this method in script and call in onchange of dropdownlist

```
`function GetId(){   alert($('#input-1option:selected').attr("value"));}`
```

if it not working please check jquery library or replace that with given CDN
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: Mohit I surgest you read the question again, the OP is not looking for a way to get the selected option's value, but the parent `li`'s id. Second your could would not work since there is no element with the id `#input-1option`